# Was Stringfellow's 1848-1868 motor a revolutionary aviation engine or just a useless low efficiency toy which never powered a flying model plane?

Tags: aviation-history, piston-engine

I took a look at the 1848 Stringfellow's aviation steam engine and I do not really understand how it was capable to power a model plane in horizontal flight as long as the motor itself was just an ordinary toy of the time and the boiler is a below-average design, as long as the fire is not surrounded by water from all sides to transfer the energy of the fuel with maximum efficiency to the working fluid. The fire burns around the upside-down cones containing water and it radiates a good part of its energy through the thin metal walls of the boiler.

The [Scientific American (Vol. 20, Iss. 11, p.69; Mar 13, 1869)](https://www.ctie.monash.edu/hargrave/stringfellow.html) says that a later version of this engine (1868) achieved a pressure of 100 $lb/in^2$, after 7 minutes from the moment the fire was started, and was able to turn two propellers 3 ft in diameter at 300 rev/min. The dry mass of the motor and boiler together was 13 lb.

> IS A FLYING MACHINE A MECHANICAL POSSIBILITY?
>
> … The organization of the Aeronautical Society, which gave its first
> exhibition at London last June, is an evidence that the belief is
> gaining rather than losing ground. … what are we to say of an engine
> weighing only sixteen lbs., and being able to work to one-horse power?
> The council of the society voted their £100 prize to Mr. Stringfellow
> for an engine of this description; and whether or not it ever becomes
> the motive power for flight, it would seem, from its ingenuity, to be
> well worth the reward. “The cylinder,” the report tells us, “is 2
> inches in diameter, stroke 3 inches, and works with a boiler pressure
> of 100 lbs. to the square inch; the engine working 300 revolutions per
> minute. The time of getting up the steam was noted; in three minutes
> after lighting the fire the pressure was 30 lbs.; in five minutes, 50
> lbs.; and in seven minutes there was the full working pressure of 100
> lbs. When started, the engine had a fair amount of duty to perform in
> driving two four-bladed screw propellers, 3 feet in diameter, at 300
> revolutions a minute.”
>
> The data for calculating the power are taken as follows: Area of
> piston, 3 inches; pressure in cylinder, 80 lbs. per square inch;
> length of stroke, 3 inches; velocity of piston, 150 feet per minute; 3
> × 80 × 150 = 36,000 foot-pounds. This makes rather more than one-horse
> power (which is reckoned at 33,000 foot-pounds). The weight of the
> engine and boiler was only 13 lbs., and it is probably the lightest
> steam engine that has ever been constructed. The engine, boiler, car,
> and propeller together were afterwards weighed, but without water and
> fuel, and were found to be 16 lbs.”
>
> This engine seems to demonstrate the possibility of making engines
> light and powerful enough for purposes of flight.

However, nothing is said about the capacity of the boiler to maintain a suitable pressure for, say, at least 30 seconds, an interval of time that would have allowed a short flight. Another thing would be, if this engine was able to fly a model plane in 1848, why did it not repeat the performance in 1868?

[image: John Stringfellow, engine, 1848]

Source: [John Stringfellow, engine, 1848](https://www.ctie.monash.edu/hargrave/stringfellow.html)

With the data in the Sci. Am. article of Mar 13, 1869, I calculated that Stringfellow's engine needed 1.54 liters of steam at 5.44 atm each second in order to work at the desired power.

Judging from the total size of the recipients that contained the steam (which is below 15 liters) and the time needed to reach the necessary pressure, of the order of 7 minutes, this engine would have functioned at most 10 seconds and then it would have needed a few minutes to build up again enough pressure for another few seconds of generating mechanical power.

[image: Stringfellow's engine needed 1.54 liters of steam at 5.44 atm each second in order to work at the desired power.]

[image: The Conquest Of The Air]

Source: [The Conquest Of The Air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnuOMzrEGf4)

**Question**: Was John Stringfellow's 1848-1868 motor a revolutionary aviation engine or just a low efficiency toy well behind its time? Was this device really capable to power the 1848 model aeroplane of the above mentioned inventor?

(A link to an exact working replica of the 1848 engine and plane would answer my question immediately.)

Comment: +1 for research effort, however, I'm not entirely convinced there is an objective answer to this. The engine worked: it powered a model airplane. What differentiates an "aviation engine" from a "low efficiency toy" in this context? It's an aviation engine because it powered the model successfully, it's a toy because it wouldn't power a bigger, heavier, manned aircraft. Not sure what more can be said about it.

Comment: I am not sure at all Stringfellow's engine ever powered a model plane that really flew. The story of the 1848 flights is written in a pamphlet "A few Remarks on what has been done with screw-propelled Aeroplane Machines from 1809 to 1892" written by F. J. Stringfellow, the son of the inventor (see: https://www.ctie.monash.edu/hargrave/stringfellow.html). Basically, Stringfellow Jr., declared that his father was the first person who built a working heavier-than-air flying machine. This is just a claim. (In 1892 there were model planes capable of flight, built by others.)

Comment: In that case, consider editing your question to make it clearer that what you're asking is not whether it was a "proper" engine or a toy, but whether it flew or not. These are two very different questions.

Comment: Agree with Dracula, to suit this site, the question should be about flight, not about the viability of the engine. An interesting question even as it originally stands, but as such maybe better suited for engineering stack exchange or some other site on SE.

Comment: I have already updated the question adding "Was this device really capable to power the 1848 model aeroplane of the above mentioned inventor?"

Comment: There is absolutely no evidence that somebody before Alphonse Penaud flew model planes. This inventor flew his Planophore at Tuileries Gardens in Paris, France, on August 18, 1871. The Planophore, powered by a rubber band driven pusher propeller, flew 181 feet in 11 seconds. (see: http://www.flyingmachines.org/pend.html). John Stringfellow himself never claimed powered flights.

Comment: Had the 13 lb engine+boiler of John Stringfellow really generated 1 hp, continuous power, it would have become, then in 1848, even 1868, an extremely successful motor for powering tools (like a lathe) in small workshops, for powering small river boats, steam cars, draisines, even bicycles. In reality, Stringfellow's motor was a nothing. It worked just in pulses of a few seconds, followed by minutes of pause necessary for rebuilding the steam pressure.